# Seekbar run with postion on custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-seekbar

I am developing a music player where songs inflated in list view in my list row. I have played pause button and a seek bar. When I click on play button of first song in listview, first song will start playing but all the songs seek bar changes its postion start to run.

I want to make only single seek will on single click.

Here is my code of adapter:

```
 public abstract class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements  SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mStringFilterList;
    LayoutInflater inflter;
    public ImageView img2,img3;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    SeekBar songProgressBar;

  public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.countryList = countryList;
        mStringFilterList =  countryList;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryList.size();
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countryList) {
        this.countryList = countryList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_itemss, null);

        String hello = String.valueOf(countryList.get(position));
        String s = hello;
        int s1 = s.lastIndexOf("=");
        int s2 = s.lastIndexOf("}");

        String strSub = s.substring(s1+1,s2/*s.lastIndexOf("=")*/);
        Log.d("Hello",hello);       
        String henno1 = String.valueOf(hello.length());
        Log.d("hellya",henno1);
        songProgressBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);

        TextView country = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        country.setText(strSub);

        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);

        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

        img2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        img3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Pause --",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
                   }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Resume --",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null){
                       mp.start();                       
                  }
                }
            }
        });
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();
                Log.d("parentrow", String.valueOf(parentRow));
                //  Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Position is --"+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int songIndex = position;

                currentSongIndex=songIndex;

                playSong(currentSongIndex);




                songProgressBar.setFocusable(true);
                songProgressBar.setEnabled(true);
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);

                }        
            }
        });


        ImageView img =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Added to Playlist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                file = new File(path.get(position));
                listItems.add(String.valueOf(file));     
                customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void  playSong(int songIndex){
        // Play song
        Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Hellooo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();         

            img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);

            // set Progress bar values
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);

            // Updating progress bar
            updateProgressBar();

      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateProgressBar() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }
    public Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

            // Displaying Total Duration time

            songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            // Displaying time completed playing
            songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

            // Updating progress bar
            int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
            //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            songProgressBar.setProgress(progress(.get(j));

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {
    }    
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

        // forward or backward to certain seconds
        mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

        // update timer progress again
        updateProgressBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using same reference of seekBar in all places or different?

Comment: yes!!!! i am using same reference.

Comment: Are all the seekbars at the same value? Have you tried scrolling and seeing what happens?

Comment: yes bro when i scroll any of  the seek Bar the current playing song forwards.